# Convert mySQL record into Elastic Search record

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

Apologies if this has been asked and answered before.

I'm looking for a way to take a fairly complicated SQL db record and convert into something I can insert into an Elastic Search index - essentially, I need to export a row from the DB, convert it, then use a curl POST to insert it directly into the intended ES index.

The record has a lot of columns (30+) and creating them manually looks like it'll take a very long time, with a lot of trial and error, and there's quite a few to do.

Sorry if that's a bit vague, not sure how else to articulate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you hoping to do this all with SQL? Or are you writing a program to do the conversion and insert it into ES?

Comment: Why dont you use [logstash - jdbc input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html) and `ruby` filter for data massaging that cant be handled at SQL level.

Comment: Why you need to convert it. Why cant you sent the exported query result(json format) directly to Elastic Server